# ошибка: SDL/SDL_gamecontroller.h: No such file or directory #include <SDL/SDL_gamecontroller.h>

Tags: qtcreator

собрал Urho3D-1.8-ALPHA (всё собралось)

решил собрать простейший пример  из [Urho3D](https://urho3d.io/)

Но почему то пишет файл который даже в проекте не находится(защищённый внутренний) что нету заголовочного SDL_gamecontroller.h , при этом его именно нету такой файл есть в SDL2/SDL_gamecontroller.h НО я не хочу исправлять внутрисистемные файлы

Вот не могу понять как он (cmake) смог собрать все примеры, а я не справляюсь (все библиотеки подлючил), вот вот локализированная ошибка :

**urno_example1.pro**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2021-12-21T11:52:47
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = urno_example1
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
#        main.cpp \
#        mainwindow.cpp
    HelloWorld.cpp \
    Sample.inl

HEADERS += \
#        mainwindow.h
    HelloWorld.h \
    Sample.h

INCLUDEPATH +=/home/dima/ogre/Urho3D-1.8-ALPHA/Source/ThirdParty/SDL/include \
        /home/dima/ogre/Urho3D-1.8-ALPHA/build/Source/ThirdParty/SDL/include/generated \
        /usr/local/include/Urho3D                                             \
#    /home/dima/ogre/Urho3D-1.8-ALPHA/build/include/Urho3D                    \
#    /home/dima/ogre/Urho3D-1.8-ALPHA/build/include/Urho3D/ThirdParty/SDL     \
#    /usr/include/SDL                                                         \
#    /usr/include/SDL2


unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/Urho3D/ -lUrho3D

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/Urho3D-1.8-ALPHA/Source/Urho3D
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/Urho3D-1.8-ALPHA/Source/Urho3D

unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/Urho3D/libUrho3D.a

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/Urho3D-1.8-ALPHA/build/Source/ThirdParty/SDL/ -lSDL

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/Urho3D-1.8-ALPHA/Source/ThirdParty/SDL/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/Urho3D-1.8-ALPHA/Source/ThirdParty/SDL/include

unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../ogre/Urho3D-1.8-ALPHA/build/Source/ThirdParty/SDL/libSDL.a


# --- linux ---

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lOpenGL

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lGLEW

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lglut

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lGLU

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL


//
// Copyright (c) 2008-2019 the Urho3D project.
//
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
//
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
// THE SOFTWARE.
//
```

**HelloWorld.h**

```
    #pragma once
    #include "SDL.h"
    #include "Sample.h"
    
    /// This first example, maintaining tradition, prints a "Hello World" message.
    /// Furthermore it shows:
    ///     - Using the Sample / Application classes, which initialize the Urho3D engine and run the main loop
    ///     - Adding a Text element to the graphical user interface
    ///     - Subscribing to and handling of update events
    class HelloWorld : public Sample
    {
        URHO3D_OBJECT(HelloWorld, Sample);
    
    public:
        /// Construct.
        explicit HelloWorld(Context* context);
    
        /// Setup after engine initialization and before running the main loop.
        void Start() override;
    
    protected:
        /// Return XML patch instructions for screen joystick layout for a specific sample app, if any.
        String GetScreenJoystickPatchString() const override { return
            "<patch>"
            "    <add sel=\"/element/element[./attribute[@name='Name' and @value='Hat0']]\">"
            "        <attribute name=\"Is Visible\" value=\"false\" />"
            "    </add>"
            "</patch>";
        }
    
    private:
        /// Construct a new Text instance, containing the 'Hello World' String, and add it to the UI root element.
        void CreateText();
        /// Subscribe to application-wide logic update events.
        void SubscribeToEvents();
        /// Handle the logic update event.
        void HandleUpdate(StringHash eventType, VariantMap& eventData);
    };

/usr/local/include/Urho3D/Input/InputConstants.h:31: ошибка: SDL/SDL_gamecontroller.h: No such file or directory
 #include <SDL/SDL_gamecontroller.h>
                                    ^

жалуется на /usr/local/include/Urho3D/Input/InputConstants.h
```

Как  бы пропустить эту придирку всёравно контролер не буду подключать.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При сборке Urho3D у вас где-то должна появиться папка `SDL` с файлом `SDL_gamecontroller.h` нужно её подцепить к include путям и можно будет пропустить эту придирку.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan подцепил но почему-то он их не видит   (ща фотки добавлю)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем тут https://github.com/SirNate0/Urho-Project-Template ответ ,
отдельный атомизированный проект , надо просто только свои  .cpp .h поставить и всё будет ок :3

Ответ дали мне мне тут https://discourse.urho3d.io/t/error-sdl-sdl-gamecontroller-h-no-such-file-or-directory-include-sdl-sdl-gamecontroller-h/7107/4